# ACF expression using FFT method

Tags: fft, autocorrelation

It is known that the `ACF` of a `2D` digital image can be obtained by computing the inverse Fourier transform `(FT)` of the product of the `FT` of the image and its complex conjugate. That is:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot figure out the expression for the inverse of G(p,q). I’d appreciate any idea, help, or suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: but don't you have $G(p,q)$ written ?

Comment: Oh no! i'm seeking the inverse of $G(p,q)$. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: but $\vert f(x,y) e^{-j 2 \pi (\frac{px}{M}+\frac{qx}{N})} \vert = \vert f(x,y) \vert$

Comment: That can't be true. You're saying the absolute value of the Fourier transformed image is the same as the original image?

Comment: Given that $|e^{-j2\pi(\frac{px}{M} + \frac{qy}{N})}| = 1$, I can see what you mean. However, I can't see how that $\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}{|f(x,y)|^2} = G(p,q)$. At least I've tried that in Matlab and it doesn't give me the same result. What can i be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the sums are inside the $|\cdot|^2$?